# How to prove that any integer bigger or equal to 3 can be the exponent of a non-abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation

To be clear, by the exponent of a group $G$, I mean the smallest number $n$ for which $x^n = e$, for any $x$ in $G$.

I recently encountered a problem in which I had to prove that for any natural number $n$ bigger or equal than $3$, there exists a finite non-abelian group with an exponent equal to $n$.

The first rule I discovered was that if two groups the have exponents, say, $a_1$ and $a_2$,then the direct product of these groups has an exponent of $\operatorname{lcm}(a_1,a_2)$ (least common multiple), meaning that if $a_1$ and $a_2$ belong to our list of numbers then so does $\operatorname{lcm}(a_1,a_2)$;  $(1)$

The second thing I did was prove that if $n$ is an odd prime number, then there exists a finite non-abelian group with exponent $n$. The proof is by example: I took all upper triangular 3x3 matrices with numbers from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (the residue class modulo $p$) with only $1$'s on the diagonal. I then proved that any such matrix raised to the power $p$ is equal to the identity $I_3$. Since $p$ is prime, $p$ is the smallest power for which this is true, and therefore $p$ is the exponent of the group;  $(2)$

The third thing I did was to use $(1)$ and $(2)$ to prove that it works for any square-free odd integer.

I then realized that if you take the direct product of an abelian and a non-abelian group, then the result is non-abelian. This means that we now have also unlocked the square-free even numbers, since we can easily find an example of a group (not necessarily non-commutative), say $(\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$, which has an exponent of $2$. By $(2)$ this means that there exists a group $G$ with an exponent of $n$, for any square-free number $n$.  $(3)$

I don't really know how to continue, the least I need to prove is that if the rule holds for a prime number $p$, then it holds for all powers of $p$.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your maths look pretty (basically, put `$...$` around all your maths-stuff, so for example `$\gcd(a_1, a_2)$` renders as $\gcd(a_1, a_2)$, and `$\mathbb{Z}$` renders as $\mathbb{Z}$, while we need to get slightly more involved to get lcm working: `$\operatorname{lcm}(a_1, a_2)$` renders as $\operatorname{lcm}(a_1, a_2)$.)

Comment: @user1729 thank you! I think I changed it all now.

Comment: Brilliant! I added in the `\operatorname{lcm}` and also the `\mathbb{Z}_p` rather than `Z(p)`, which I guess is what you were aiming for?

Comment: Thanks! :D Yes, that was what I was aiming for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G$ is a non-abelian group of exponent $p$, then
$$
G \times \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^n \mathbb{Z}}
$$
is a non-abelian group of exponent $p^n$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm just a high school student and I have no clue what that notation means, could you please explain it to me or at least send me a link to a page where I can learn? I mean the Z/p^nZ part.

Comment: @Marius It just means $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$. The idea of the notation is that we can view $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ as a "quotient group" of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$, with kernel $p^n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Because since p is a prime number p^k will hit all numbers eventually or? And when I multiply p^a1 with p^a2, it's like I add a1+a2 modulo n. Does this work with composite numbers aswell?

Comment: @marius just mean the cyclic group of order $p^n$.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost done.

Let $n\geqslant 3$ and let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n$.

Let $U_3(p)$ denote your non-abelian group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$.

Then $U_3(p)\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ is non-abelian of exponent $n$.

Comment: Could you please explain what the U3(p) is? I have never seen this notation before, although I suppose it's pretty standard.

Comment: @Marius It is simply the upper triangular 3x3 matrices with numbers from $\mathbb{Z}_p$, as in the question.

Comment: @Marius as I said I meant **your** group, the one you'd already used.

Comment: I was just courious about the choice of notation, that's all. In fact, now that I think about it, it's actually pretty simple, U comes from "upper" as in "upper triangular", 3 denotes the number of rows and columns and '(p)' tells me that I'm working in residue class p, right?

Comment: I used the notation because it is what I was brought up to use for the "unitriangular group". I see that it now seems standard to use $UT(n,p)$.